# What's the easiest way to parse a string like this into an array without double quotes?

Tags: c#

Is there a one-liner or something? The string would be in the form of

```
["abc", "cde", "efg", ... "foo"]
```

For example:

```
["CD", "IN", "NN"]
```

Another example:

```
["NNS","CC","NNS","IN","JJ","NN",",","NN"]
```

So the element can be a comma as well.

Comment: Use the JSON library to parse it.

Comment: All the answers below still work after your edit - the comma will be interpreted as just another string value.

Comment: @helb's answer doesn't work for that edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the string is standard JSON, use [Json.NET](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/):

```
const string json = @"[""Hello"",""World""]";
var jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(json);

foreach (string s in jsonObject)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

If the string in your question is guaranteed to be a simple JSON array of strings, then the other answers would be a better solution; simply change `dynamic` to `string[]`, `IEnumerable<string>` or `JArray`, depending on your needs.

Comment: If you know it's gonna be a `string[]`, why deserialize as `dynamic`?

Comment: We're all assuming the string is JSON to begin with. I use `dynamic` as a matter of habit because very rarely is my own JSON just a simple array. If you know the exact format then yes, it does make sense to deserialize to a known type and avoid the dynamic runtime.

Comment: Not trying to be a dick but if you're using dynamic everywhere out of habit why even work in C#? I don't think it's very hard to use the type safe deserialization options in json.NET. In fact, I have code to do it for 100's of types that are all 100's of times more complex than the OP's example.

Comment: I'm not. I use it in almost all cases where I deserialize JSON because, as I wrote earlier, very rarely is the JSON I have to deserialize so simple. The OP is now aware of several ways of parsing that string, and that's a good thing. I'm bringing some additional context to light, that's all. :)

Comment: @evanmcdonnal This is the most general case answer that can be given to the question asked. Rambling about data contracts would be well beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: @Asad perhaps except I think it encourages someone to use bad practices when the OP is obviously not going to know any better. Pretty soon the OP will have thousands of lines of code that all use `dynamic` for no reason :p

Answer (score 2):

See http://james.newtonking.com/json - there is also a Nuget package for this, which is the first result (for me, anyway) when you search "json".

```
string json; // Your string.
string[] jsonAsArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(json);
```

Comment: +1 for static typing :) (although you can probably use the generic version of `DeserializeObject` to avoid a cast)

Comment: Yeah I don't think this is actually using the correct deserialization method but the concept is the same regardless.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I'm sure you can implicitly use the method as I've shown - will quickly test that now.

Comment: @NickBull actually, I'm pretty sure you're right and my code is wrong. `Deserialize<T>` is actually an instance method on `JsonSerializer` where as `DeserializeObject` and `DeserializeObject<T>` are the equivalent static methods in `JsonConvert`

Comment: Ahh - the static method does require a cast if it isn't generic - thanks @Asad

Comment: @NickBull yeah `DeserializeObject<T>` is a better option here.

Answer (score 1):

A one liner? Assuming you're using json.NET, your json is just a string array so the following will do it for you;

```
string[] myJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(jsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
myString.TrimStart("[\"").TrimEnd("\"]").Split(new string[] { "\",\"", "\" ,\"" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```